# How to count of 5 star, 4 star, 3 star, 2 star and 1 star by parameter id?

Tags: magento2, product-review

I want to count all review products in Magento 2 like :

There are 5 reviews 1 star

There are 3 reviews 2 star
....

Pls Help me, Thanks

Comment: you have to check that link hope it's help to you http://www.knowledgebags.com/how-to-get-number-of-product-reviews-magento-2/

Comment: thanks but it only shows the total number of reviews, not individually how many 1 star, 2 star reviews,...

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
<?php
$productId = 'your_product_id';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$storeManager  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
?>
<?php if($ratingSummary){ ?>
<div class="product-reviews-summary short">
    <div class="rating-summary">
        <div title="<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
            <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-actions">
        <?php echo __('('.$reviewCount.') Reviews'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Note** Don't use objectmanager. It's not good practice.

Comment: thanks
but it only shows the total number of reviews, not individually how many 1 star, 2 star reviews,...

Comment: added another answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and call this method with your product ID. Also make sure you have only 1 rating option in admin.

```
public function getAllStart($pid) {
    $review = $this->_objectReview->getCollection()     //\Magento\Review\Model\Review $reviewFactory (_objectReview)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status_id', 1)
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $pid)          //$pid = > your current product ID
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFieldToSelect('review_id')
    ;
    $review->getSelect()->columns('detail.detail_id')->joinInner(
            ['vote' => $review->getTable('rating_option_vote')], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id', array('review_value' => 'vote.value')
    );
    $review->getSelect()->order('review_value DESC');
    $review->getSelect()->columns('count(vote.vote_id) as total_vote')->group('review_value');
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        $arrRatings[$i]['value'] = 0;
    }
    foreach ($review as $_result) {
        $arrRatings[$_result['review_value']]['value'] = $_result['total_vote'];
    }
    return $arrRatings;
    }
```

Note: it's not work if the site have multiple criterias ratings.

Comment: it doesn't work